# Change holoviews extension on a single plot

Tags: python, holoviews

I usually use the `bokeh` backend, but I want to be able to plot surfaces as well, as supported by the `matplotlib` backend but not by `bokeh`. Is there a way that I can designate that a particular plot should be rendered using a different backend without changing the backend used for subsequent plots? I could do the following e.g. in a Jupyter notebook:

```py
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("bokeh")

# plots involving bokeh backend
```

```py
surface = hv.Surface(np.sin(np.linspace(0,100*np.pi*2,10000)).reshape(100,100))
hv.extension("matplotlib")
surface
```

```py
hv.extension("bokeh")
# more plots involving bokeh
```

But it's rather inconvenient. Is there anything that I could do like

```py
surface = surface.opts(extension="matplotlib")
```

so that this element will be rendered with `matplotlib` but rendering other plots will be unaffected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using holoviews >=1.11.0 you can use the `hv.output` utility. First make sure to load both backends:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("bokeh", "matplotlib")
... # Various plots using bokeh
```

Now you can use the `output` utility to display a single plot using matplotlib (or plotly):

```
surface = hv.Surface(np.sin(np.linspace(0,100*np.pi*2,10000)).reshape(100,100))
hv.output(surface, backend='matplotlib')
```

If you also have to provide custom options for the different backend you can specify the backend as part of the `.opts` (or `.options` declaration):

```
hv.output(surface.opts(fig_size=200, backend='matplotlib'), backend='matplotlib')
```